# React Native: change background color of initial loading view

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

When the React Native app is running at first, there is a white view like the screenshot bellow, how can i change that view's background color? I cannot find the activity in Xcode.

[image]

Because in some cases, i restart the app, and users sees a flash (the white screen above), so i need to change the background color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @AlirezaValizade Why you think so? what is wrong? which part of the code you want? AppDelegate?

Comment: Try changing the `LaunchScreen` file. It's the first thing that shows up when your app opens. Also note that in production release there will be no bundling from the server, so no need to worry that for now.

Comment: @EnieJakiro Thanks, but LaunchScreen is different. LaunchScreen is happening after root view, if you restart the app, you will see a flash. a white screen, which is Root View.

Comment: uh I now see what you're looking for. I'm wondering, how come your users see this white screen?

Comment: @EnieJakiro if you restart the app programatically after it's loaded, they will see.

Comment: But your users can not restart the app. Only the debug.apk / debug.ipa can be restarted, since they would have access to dev menu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found it in AppDelegate.m

```
rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:0.0f green:0.64f blue:0.87f alpha:1];
```

Comment: This article was super helpful to this end, and also Android: https://medium.com/@Krizzu/how-to-change-background-color-of-rootview-in-react-native-3279417c34bb

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `LaunchScreen` file. It's the first thing that shows up when your app opens (If your bundling takes too long, you will see the white screen again. IMO the best practice is to use [splash screen](https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen).

Using splash screen, you can dismiss the Splash View (probably an image) in your componentDidMount() function like below.

```
componentDidMount() {
   // do anything while splash screen keeps, use await to wait for an async task.
   SplashScreen.hide();
}
```

Also note that, in production release, there will be no bundling from the local server, so no need to worry that for now.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have the launchscreen, it's not the case.

Comment: Glad you found what you need. But still, only dev builds can be restarted. I wouldn't mind this too much.

Comment: with react-native-restart module you can also restart production apps. just like code push, it can restart the app when js bundle is downloaded and installed.

Comment: I fully understand what you mean but can't consider it as an end user product. But still, thanks for sharing!

Comment: you're right, but in some cases I have to restart the app. for example, there are two different users in my app. one is a user, one is a teacher, and user can switch between them. user have 5 tabs , teacher have 3 tabs. as far as i know you cannot change the tabs after app have been loaded ( i mean the TabBar at the bottom ) , so after user switches the user, i have to restart the app to reset the TabBar

Comment: I guess you could achieve that by writing your own TabBar and a root component to switch between them without restarting the app. However, I can imagine myself starting the app with only user login, planning and building it. Then my customer wants teacher login, which confuses the app architecture (especially for `react-native-router-flux` :)) so in this case yes, I think `react-native-restart` would do.

Comment: actually Im using the react-native-router-flux and it's built in TabBar module. you're totally right but that needs lots of effort, so that would be goal for future.

Comment: this is not the case generated

Comment: I agree, I wasnt aware of the other answer back then.